# ¿como descargo una dependencia en Java?

Tags: dependencias

Hola estaba realizando un proyecto en java, pero el problema es que no se como descargar una dependencia, la cual es: protobuf-java-3.6.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Si usas maven puedes seguir las instrucciones de la [pagina del repositorio](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java) y seleccionar la version adecuada, o la ultima estable:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Si usas gradle seguir las [instrucciones del repositorio](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.12'
  }
}
```

En cualquier otro caso, debes buscar las instrucciones especificas para la plataforma donde lo usarás. Intenta buscar en google por `NOMBREPLATAFORMA protobuf`

Answer (score 0):

si  lo que te pasa es que no se actualiza/descargan las dependencias, puedes indicar  a maven que haga update al repositorio o en su defecto purgar tu repositorio local.

Update command:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Purge local repository:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install
```

Consultar documentación oficial: [Purge repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html)

Saludos